# How to tell Primsa to not add @Unique constraint

Tags: prisma2

Does the [VSCode Primsa Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Prisma.prisma) have rules like eslint?

Need its linter to ignore lines in schema files.

for example, given:

```
model User{
  // PaymentMethod can be shared between multiple records - not unique
  paymentMethodId        String?               @db.VarChar(30)
}
```

the auto-formatter/linter will add @unique:

```
model User{
  // PaymentMethod can be shared between multiple records - not unique
  paymentMethodId        String?               @unique @db.VarChar(30)
}
```

is there a way to do something like this?:

```
model User{
  // PaymentMethod can be shared between multiple records - not unique
/* eslint-disable */
  paymentMethodId        String?               @db.VarChar(30)
/* eslint-enable*/
}
```

It appears that the auto formatter has no configuration options currently: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema#auto-formatting
But is there a way to configure the linter portion?

**UPDATE**
This is not just an issue with the Prisma VSCode Extension:
I can confirm that even when not using the extension, Prisma tooling will add the @unique constraints. For example, it is a part of `prisma migrate` as well, so even if the schema file doesn't specify @unique the migrate tool will add it:
[image]

Also there used to be a way to change the bin Path of the formatter so you could use a specific one, but now that setting is gone as well:

[image]

Comment: A work around is to use the `--create-only` flag like so: `prisma migrate dev --create-only`. Then modify the generated migration to remove the sql commands that would do the undesired unique constraints.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue for this scenario: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/10503
and sounds like it won't be resolved until Prisma 4.
In the mean time, a work around is to use the [`--create-only` flag](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/command-reference#migrate-dev) like so: `prisma migrate dev --create-only` targeting a blank db. Then modify the generated migration to remove the sql commands that would do the undesired unique constraints before deploying to your actual db.